# Replace isql with sqsh in emacs (Ubuntu)

Tags: emacs, isql, sqsh

Using emacs on Ubuntu 11.10. I want to connect to a SQL Server database using sqsh instead of isql. I added the following to my initi.el

```
(set 'sql-sybase-program "sqsh")
(set 'sql-ms-program "sqsh")
```

It recompiles and loads successfully. However, when I use sql-ms and try to connect to the database, I am getting errors because emacs is using lower-case command parameters when it should be using upper-case command parameters. Furthermore, I can successfully connect to the database server using sqsh from the command line. When I try to run things within emacs, I get the following error:

```
sqsh: -d: Invalid integer expression

Process SQL exited abnormally with code 255
```

I did a pretty extensive Google search and I can't find much on how to do this (which makes me think it may not be possible). Obviously, I can run sqsh from within a shell, but then I lose the SQL mode integration. I'm not sure what I can / need to do to my init.el file to make this possible.

I think all I really need to do is figure out how to get emacs to send a -D not a -d to sqsh. Apparently isql doesn't care, but sqsh cares deeply about the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, the real answer is to get Emacs to use `-D` instead of `-d`. However, as a workaround, running `sql-sybase` instead of `sql-ms` seems to work fine for me.

**Update**: Try this code, it removes the `-n` option from `sql-ms-options` and redefines `sql-ms-options` to use `-D` instead of `-d` as the option to select the database:

```
(setq sql-ms-options (remove "-n" sql-ms-options))

(defun sql-comint-ms (product options)
  "Create comint buffer and connect to Microsoft SQL Server."
  ;; Put all parameters to the program (if defined) in a list and call
  ;; make-comint.
  (let ((params options))
    (if (not (string= "" sql-server))
        (setq params (append (list "-S" sql-server) params)))
    (if (not (string= "" sql-database))
        (setq params (append (list "-D" sql-database) params)))
    (if (not (string= "" sql-user))
    (setq params (append (list "-U" sql-user) params)))
    (if (not (string= "" sql-password))
    (setq params (append (list "-P" sql-password) params))
      (if (string= "" sql-user)
      ;; if neither user nor password is provided, use system
      ;; credentials.
      (setq params (append (list "-E") params))
    ;; If -P is passed to ISQL as the last argument without a
    ;; password, it's considered null.
    (setq params (append params (list "-P")))))
    (sql-comint product params)))
```

Comment: I should have tried that one myself. I even set my init.el to use sqsh for both, even though I doubt I will ever connect to a Sybase db (we use SQL Server and Postgres).

Comment: I'm going to wait another day or so, but it nobody comes up with a better solution, I'm going to accept this as the solution, simply because it does work on my system without any additional effort. Perhaps I should go in and look at the lisp for sql-mode (not that I am a great lisp hacker).

Comment: Wow. The updated idea is a bit more complicated, but works perfectly.